# Unable to add object to NSMutableArray with TFHpple

Tags: object, nsmutablearray

I tried to add object to my mutable array using `TFHlle` parse html in this code but it return null for object in my array, but in the for loop, I log the result of '[element objectForKey:@"title"]' and it returns result I want.

How I can add the result of element `[objectForKey:@"title"]` to my array?

```
TFHpple *htmlParseResult = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:self.responseData];
NSString *coursesXpathQueryString = @"//h2[@class='main']/a";
NSArray *coursesNodes = [htmlParseResult searchWithXPathQuery:coursesXpathQueryString];
NSMutableArray *fitCourse = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for (TFHppleElement *element in coursesNodes) {
    [fitCourse addObject:[element objectForKey:@"title"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
NSArray *coursesNodes = [htmlParseResult searchWithXPathQuery:coursesXpathQueryString];
```

should be change to:

```
NSArray *coursesNodes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[htmlParseResult searchWithXPathQuery:coursesXpathQueryString]];
```

I am not sure this works but you can try.